# ifelse function group in group in R

Tags: r, if-statement, duplicates, data.table

I have data set

```
ID <- c(1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4)
Eval <- c("A","A","B","B","A","A","A","A","B","B","A","A","A","B")
med <- c("c","d","k","k","h","h","c","d","h","h","h","c","h","k")
df <- data.frame(ID,Eval,med)
> df
    ID Eval med
 1   1    A   c
 2   1    A   d
 3   2    B   k
 4   2    B   k
 5   2    A   h
 6   2    A   h
 7   3    A   c
 8   3    A   d
 9   3    B   h
 10  3    B   h
 11  3    A   h
 12  4    A   c
 13  4    A   h
 14  4    B   k
```

I try to create variable `x` and `y`, group by ID and Eval. For each ID, `if Eval = A, and med = "h" or "k"`, I set `x = 1`, other wise `x = 0`, `if Eval = B and med = "h" or "k"`, I set `y = 1`, other wise `y = 0`. I use the way I don't like it, I got answer but it seem like not that great

```
df <- data.table(df)
setDT(df)[, count := uniqueN(med) , by = .(ID,Eval)]
setDT(df)[Eval == "A", x:= ifelse(count == 1 & med %in% c("k","h"),1,0), by=ID]
setDT(df)[Eval == "B", y:= ifelse(count == 1 & med %in% c("k","h"),1,0), by=ID]


     ID Eval med count  x  y
 1:  1    A   c     2  0 NA
 2:  1    A   d     2  0 NA
 3:  2    B   k     1 NA  1
 4:  2    B   k     1 NA  1
 5:  2    A   h     1  1 NA
 6:  2    A   h     1  1 NA
 7:  3    A   c     3  0 NA
 8:  3    A   d     3  0 NA
 9:  3    B   h     1 NA  1
10:  3    B   h     1 NA  1
11:  3    A   h     3  0 NA
12:  4    A   c     2  0 NA
13:  4    A   h     2  0 NA
14:  4    B   k     1 NA  1
```

Then I need to collapse the row to get unique ID, I don't know how to collapse rows, any idea?

The output

```
 ID x y
 1  0 0
 2  1 1
 3  0 1
 4  0 1
```

Comment: Shouldn't the 'y' for ID 1 be 0 as there are only NAs in that

Comment: Yeah, you're right

Comment: For line 11 of your data, shouldn't `x` be `1` since Eval is `A` and med is `h`?

Comment: @Maiasaura, line 11, ID 3 with Eval A, you can see it has Eval "c", "d","h", it's not in the group "h" and "k". so it should be 0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We create the 'x' and 'y' variables grouped by 'ID' without the NA elements directly coercing the logical vector to binary (`as.integer`)

```
df[, x := as.integer(Eval == "A" & count ==1 & med %in% c("h", "k")) , by = ID]
```

and similarly for 'y'

```
df[, y := as.integer(Eval == "B" & count ==1 & med %in% c("h", "k")) , by = ID]
```

and summarise it, using `any` after grouping by "ID"

```
df[, lapply(.SD, function(x) as.integer(any(x))) , ID, .SDcols = x:y]
#   ID x y
#1:  1 0 0
#2:  2 1 1
#3:  3 0 1
#4:  4 0 1
```

---

If we need a compact approach, instead of assinging (`:=`), we summarise the output grouped by "ID", "Eval" based on the conditions and then grouped by 'ID',  we check if there is `any` TRUE values in 'x' and 'y' by looping over the columns described in the `.SDcols`.

```
setDT(df)[,  if(any(uniqueN(med)==1 & med %in% c("h", "k"))) {
        .(x= Eval=="A", y= Eval == "B") } else .(x=FALSE, y=FALSE),
     by = .(ID, Eval)][, lapply(.SD, any) , by = ID, .SDcols = x:y]
#  ID     x     y
#1:  1 FALSE FALSE
#2:  2  TRUE  TRUE
#3:  3 FALSE  TRUE
#4:  4 FALSE  TRUE
```

If needed, we can convert to binary similar to the approach showed in the first solution.

Comment: there is anyway we don't use setDT(df)[, count := uniqueN(med) , by = .(ID,Eval)], then how to collapse the rows?

Comment: @Stat Updated with a compact approach.  The logical vector can be easily converted to binary.

Answer (score 6):

The OP's goal...

> "I try to create variable x and y, group by ID and Eval. For each ID, if Eval = A, and med = "h" or "k", I set x = 1, other wise x = 0, if Eval = B and med = "h" or "k", I set y = 1, other wise y = 0. [...] Then I need to collapse the row to get unique ID"

can be simplified to...

> For each ID and Eval, flag if all med values are h or all med values are k.

```
setDT(df) # only do this once
df[, all(med=="k") | all(med=="h"), by=.(ID,Eval)][, dcast(.SD, ID ~ Eval, fun=any)]

   ID     A     B
1:  1 FALSE FALSE
2:  2  TRUE  TRUE
3:  3 FALSE  TRUE
4:  4 FALSE  TRUE
```

To see what `dcast` is doing, read `?dcast` and try running just the first part on its own, `df[, all(med=="k") | all(med=="h"), by=.(ID,Eval)]`.

The change to use x and y instead of A and B is straightforward but ill-advised (since unnecessary renaming can be confusing and lead to extra work when there are new Eval values); and ditto the change for 1/0 instead of TRUE/FALSE (since the values captured are actually boolean).

Comment: That is a nice one.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my `dplyr` solution since I find it more readable than `data.table`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID, Eval) %>%
  mutate(
    count = length(unique(med)),
    x = ifelse(Eval == "A" &
                 count == 1 & med %in% c("h", "k"), 1, 0),
    y = ifelse(Eval == "B" &
                 count == 1 & med %in% c("h", "k"), 1, 0)
  )   %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(x1 = max(unique(x)),
            y1 = max(unique(y)))
```

Answer (score 1):

A one liner solution for collapsing the rows of your result :

```
df[,lapply(.SD,function(i) {ifelse(1 %in% i,ifelse(!0 %in% i,1,0),0)}),.SDcols=x:y,by=ID]

   ID x y
1:  1 0 0
2:  2 1 1
3:  3 0 1
4:  4 0 1
```